# Doctrine decode function

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm, decode, query-builder

In my Symfony2 project, I want to get the sum of a column (Field1) only for some lines (Field2 = 1):

```
id     Field1    Field2
1      10        1
2      20        1
3      30        0
4      40        1
5      50        0
```

In this example, I want a result of 70 (sum of lines 1, 2 and 4).

Since I Work with Oracle, I have this query working well in my SQL GUI :

```
SELECT
SUM(decode(Field2, 1, Field1, 0)) AS total 
FROM myTable
```

Since Doctrine doesn't recognize Oracle [decode function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm%20Decode%20function), I Tried to create mine :

```
namespace MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode;

/**
 * "DECODE" "(" Expression "," Search "," Result "," Default ")"
 */
class DecodeFunction extends FunctionNode
{
    public $expression;
    public $search;
    public $result;
    public $default;

    public function getSql(SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'decode(' . $this->expression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ','
        . $this->search->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ','
        . $this->result->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ','
        . $this->default->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }

    public function parse(Parser $parser)
    {
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);

        $this->expression = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->search = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->result = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);

        $this->default = $parser->StringPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }
}
```

config.yml

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true
                ...
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        decode: MyBundle\DQL\DecodeFunction
```

And my querybuilder :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');
$qb
   ->select('SUM(decode(e.Field2, :expect, e.Field1, :default)')
   ->setParameter('expect', 1)
   ->setParameter('default', 0);
```

But I got this error :

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 62 near 'Field2,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.
```

So what I'm doing wrong?
Maybe is there a simpler solution?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't you missed a closing quote?

Comment: Is Field1 and Field2 the sql column name or the property name of your MyTable Object? DQL expects you to use the object's attribute and not the column name.

Comment: Why isn't your custom DQL function inside a `class Decode extends FunctionNode` class? Did you add your custom DQL to your `config.yml` under `doctrine: orm: dql: string_functions: Decode: MyBundle\DQL\Decode`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I was on week-end and couldn't answer. So 1/ I just missed the quote during the copy/paste :). 2/ Field1 and Field2 are the object's attribute and 3/ Yes of course my code is in a class that extends FunctionNode and I correctly updated my config.yml file.

Comment: I updated my code to avoid any confusion.